# probability of having cycle in a random directed graph with a given in-degree distribution

Tags: probability, graph-theory, probability-distributions, random-graphs

Consider directed graph $G \left(V, E\right)$. Let random variable $N$ be the in-degree of a vertex. We assume that in-degree values are i.i.d random variables with PMF $f_N(n)$.

1- What is the probability of having no directed cycle of size $k$ in graph $G$?

2- Is there any tight bound? A trivial but very loose upper bound is $\binom{|V|}{k}\big(f_N(k)\big)^k$.

PS: if it helps, we can assume that $N$ has a discrete Weibull distribution.

Comment: @joriki, But this is a directed graph. We can say for any two vertices $u,v$, the probability that there is the edge $u\to v$ is $p$ independent of all other possible edges. Wouldn't that lead to iid in-degrees?

Comment: @DirkGently: You're right, sorry, I missed the directed bit -- I've removed my comment. But then my question becomes: What does "which is not true in general" mean? You're specifying a model for a graph, and you're specifying that the in-degrees are i.i.d. random variables. What's this "general" case in which this is not true?

Comment: That seems extraneous to me too. It seems that a bit of context is missing here.

Comment: @joriki, I have removed "which is not true in general".

Comment: @DirkGently, if it helps to better understand the problem, the indegree distribution is very intractable, but can be approximated by a Weibull distribution.

Comment: I still don't understand what exactly you're specifying. You talk about intractable distributions being approximated, but they don't seem to be part of the model you want treated here. But then there's no complete model so far -- the distribution of the edges is required in order to answer the questions you pose.

Comment: @joriki, you are saying that, it is almost impossible to say anything for a general distribution $f_N(n)$. Right? I have edited the question.

Comment: No, it seems I'm not making myself clear. Of course you can keep the distribution general if you like. The problem is that you're only specifying a distribution for the in-degrees but not for the edges. The distribution for the in-degrees is compatible with many different distributions for the edges, which lead to different answers to your questions; in other words, the answers to your questions are not determined by the distributions of the in-degrees. Perhaps you're implicitly making additional assumptions that you need to explicate in order to complete the model?

Comment: Now I get your point. I did not derive that probability yet.

Comment: @Hossein Would I be correct in assuming that for a given vertex $v$ and two vertex sets $V_1$ and $V_2$, where $|V_1|=|V_2|$ and $v$ is not in either $V_1$ or $V_2$, you have that probability that $V_1$ is the set of vertices with an edge leading into $v$ is equal to the probability that $V_2$ is the set of vertices with an edge leading into $v$?

Comment: @DPoole , yes you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a handle on the probability that there is a cycle of length $k$, let's first find the probability that a particular edge is present in the graph. Let $n=|V|$.

Let $\mathcal{N}$ denote the random in-degree of a vertex $y$ and let $x$ be a vertex other than $y$. Then
\begin{align*}
P(\vec{xy} \in G) &= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} P(\vec{xy} \in G | \mathcal{N}=k) P(\mathcal{N}=k) \\ &= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{k}{n-1} P(\mathcal{N}=k) = \frac{\mu}{n-1},
\end{align*}
where $\mu$ is the expected in-degree of a generic vertex. In the argument above, I use the fact that conditioned on $\mathcal{N}=k$, the set of vertices with edges leading into $y$ is uniformly distributed on all $k$-sets of $V \setminus \{y\}$. In particular, 
$$
P(\vec{xy} \in G | \mathcal{N}=k) = \frac{{n-2 \choose k-1}}{{n-1 \choose k}} = \frac{k}{n-1}.
$$

Now fix a potential cycle of length $k$. What is the probability that $x_1 \to x_2 \to \ldots \to x_k \to x_1$ is present? Now, because each of these potential edges lead into distinct vertices, whether or not the edges of the form $\vec{x_1 x_2}, \vec{x_2 x_3}, \ldots, \vec{x_k x_1}$ are present are independent events. Therefore
$$
P(x_1 \to x_2 \to \ldots \to x_k \to x_1 \text{ is present}) = \left(\frac{\mu}{n-1} \right)^k.
$$

Now
\begin{align*}
P(\exists \text{ cycle of length }k) &\leq E[\#\text{ of cycles of length }k] \\ &= {n \choose k} (k-1)! \left(\frac{\mu}{n-1} \right)^k \leq \left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^k \frac{\mu^k}{k}.
\end{align*}

This bound is "tight" in the following sense: If $f_N(n)$ is binomially distributed with $n-1$ trials and success probability $p=\frac{c}{n}$, where $c$ is fixed, then we are looking at the random graph $G(n, p=c/n)$. The number of cycles of length $k$ is asymptotically Poisson distributed with mean $\mu^k/k$ [$k$ is fixed here].

To find a workable lower bound, it depends on the range of the parameters that you are interested in. If $k$ is small and $\mu$ is large enough, then you may suspect that the number of cycles of length $k$ is asymptotically Poisson distributed with mean about $\mu^k/k$. In this case, the probability that there are no cycles of length $k$ tends to $e^{-\mu^k/k}$. Using the Chen-Stein method, you can find an upper bound on $|P(\text{no cycle})-e^{-\lambda}|,$ where $\lambda = E[\#\text{ of cycles of length }k]$.

[See Theorem 1 in this paper for the Chen-Stein method.](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1177012015)